# Difficulty changing dynamically generated table cell background onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on making a pixel art painter, and this is beyond puzzling.

As of right now, I have a table that is being dynamically generated based on user specified amounts for "Rows" and "Columns" This works perfectly fine (Although it doesn't seem to work in JSFiddle, but I can assure you that it does indeed work on a webpage as you can see here on my test [site](http://afrohorse.netau.net/pixel/)  ).

What I'm trying to accomplish now can be seen in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k8UgT/634/)
Pretty straight forward, trying to change "TD" tag's css onclick.

I can't seem to get that functionality working with a dynamically generated table.

Here is what I am currently trying ([**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/y94K8/))

**HTML:**

```
Row Count:<input type="text" id="rowcount" />
Column Count:<input type="text" id="columncount" />
<input type="button" onclick="createTable();" value="Create Table" />
<div id="box"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
table{
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
}
td{
    padding:10px;
    margin:10px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}
.active {
    background-color:#aaa;
}
```

**JS/jQuery:**

```
function createTable() {

mytable = $('<table></table>').attr({
    id: "basicTable"
});
var rows = new Number($("#rowcount").val());
var cols = new Number($("#columncount").val());
var tr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    var row = $('<tr></tr>').attr({
        class: ["class1", "class2", "class3"].join(' ')
    }).appendTo(mytable);
    for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        $('<td></td>').text("text1").appendTo(row);
    }

}
console.log("TTTTT:" + mytable.html());
mytable.appendTo("#box");


}

$(function () {
    $('td').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });
});
```

Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it won't work.  Since the entire `table` are created *dynamically* they are not getting attached to the `document` (ie., [*The problem with dynamically created elements, is that they aren't born with the same event handlers as the existing elements.*](http://toddmotto.com/attaching-event-handlers-to-dynamically-created-javascript-elements/) ).

So you have to go for event delegation attached to document.

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('click', 'td', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });
});
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y94K8/2/)

Hope you understood.

Answer (score 2):

You are binding click on 'td' before 'td' is created. Bind click inside createTable() method after 'td's have been added to the DOM.

```
function createTable()
{
    // your code

    $('td').click(function () 
    {
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });
}
```

Adding jsfiddle link.
http://jsfiddle.net/y94K8/4/