# jQuery code to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('click', 'td', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });
});
```

Can someone please show what this code would be in vanilla javascript?

[Difficulty changing dynamically generated table cell background onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22105868/difficulty-changing-dynamically-generated-table-cell-background-onclick/50448074#50448074)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The outside wrapper function in the original code was unnecessary because the `document` object always exists, so that part doesn't need to be replicated.

For the rest:

- When the document is clicked...
- ...check to see what the source element's type is.
- ...If it is a `<td>`...
- ...toggle it's active class.

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(evt){
  if(evt.target.nodeName === "TD"){
    evt.target.classList.toggle("active");
  }
});
```

Comment: That line should be
`if (evt.target.nodeName === "TD")` right?

Comment: @IshT. Yes. Sorry! Updated.